# Howto Tell if a System authenticate with password only or through PAM

Tags: ssh, password, authentication, pam

If my computer has the pam package installed and has the directory `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, does it mean for sure when I ssh to my computer, I am authenticated through pam modules? The `/etc/pam.d/sshd` looks like this:

```
  #%PAM-1.0
  auth       include      system-auth
  account    required     pam_nologin.so
  account    include      system-auth
  password   include      system-auth
  session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
  session    include      system-auth
  session    required     pam_loginuid.so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically the default is that `sshd` does *not* use PAM. From the [`sshd_config`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html) manpage:

> **UsePAM**  Enables the Pluggable Authentication Module interface. [...] The default is ``no''

But this option is almost universally enabled by SSH installations by OS distributions and default config files and such. You can check if it's enabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` if you want to be sure though.

However, even when PAM is in use by `sshd`, you can still be authenticated with an SSH key, which bypasses the PAM authentication part (PAM accounting and session management are still done).